# Is there a better way to do dependency injection in Swift than this ?

Tags: swift, generics, design-patterns, dependency-injection

New to swift, I was trying to create a service registry:

```
class ServiceRegistry {

    static var instance = ServiceRegistry()

    private var registry = [String:AnyObject]()
    private init(){}

    func register<T>(key:T, value:AnyObject) {
        self.registry["\(T.self)"] = value
    }

    func get<T>(_:T) -> AnyObject? {
        return registry["\(T.self)"]
    }

}
```

but is not super friendly:

Register:

```
 ServiceRegistry.instance.register(CacheServiceProtocol.self, value:ImageCacheService())
```

Retrieve:

```
if let cache = ServiceRegistry.instance.get(CacheServiceProtocol) as? CacheServiceProtocol { ... }
```

Any better way ? It would be useful to get rid of the `as? CacheServiceProtocol` in the `if let ...`

Answer (score 6):

**[Swinject](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject)** is a dependency injection framework for Swift. In your case, you can use it without the cast with `as?`.

Register:

```
let container = Container()
container.register(CacheServiceProtocol.self) { _ in ImageCacheService() }
```

Retrieve:

```
let cache = container.resolve(CacheServiceProtocol.self)!
```

Here `cache` is inferred as `CacheServiceProtocol` type. The `resolve` method returns `nil` if the specified type is not registered. We know `CacheServiceProtocol` is already registered, so the force-unwrap with `!` is used.

**UPDATE**

I didn't exactly answer to the question. An implementation to remove the cast is storing factory closures instead of values in the `registry`. Here is the example. I also modified the type of `key`.

```
class ServiceRegistry {
    static var instance = ServiceRegistry()

    private var registry = [String:Any]()
    private init(){}

    func register<T>(key:T.Type, factory: () -> T) {
        self.registry["\(T.self)"] = factory
    }

    func get<T>(_:T.Type) -> T? {
        let factory = registry["\(T.self)"] as? () -> T
        return factory.map { $0() }
    }
}
```

Register:

```
ServiceRegistry.instance.register(CacheServiceProtocol.self) {
    return ImageCacheService()
}
```

Retrieve:

```
// The type of cache is CacheServiceProtocol? without a cast.
let cache = ServiceRegistry.instance.get(CacheServiceProtocol.self)
```

Using `@autoclosure` might be also good.

Comment: This blog post about Swinject might be also helpful: https://yoichitgy.github.io/post/dependency-injection-framework-for-swift-introduction-to-swinject/

Answer (score 1):

I see your attempt to implement *Service Locator* design pattern. It's not *Dependency Injection* itself, but these two patterns actually can supplement each other.

I did implement a Service Locator in Swift 2 as well and I'm pretty happy with the result. Take a look at my code here: [ServiceLocator.swift](https://gist.github.com/werediver/57aed2407f63163d3246) (ready to use) or [BasicServiceLocator.swift](https://gist.github.com/werediver/f00f23dbfddfd646f96c) and [LazyServiceLocator.swift](https://gist.github.com/werediver/66ff8f13c900e9871070) (with usage examples).

Here is the basic concept:

```
protocol ServiceLocator {

    func getService<T>(type: T.Type) -> T?
    func getService<T>() -> T?

}

extension ServiceLocator {

    func getService<T>() -> T? {
        return getService(T)
    }

}

func typeName(some: Any) -> String {
    return (some is Any.Type) ? "\(some)" : "\(some.dynamicType)"
}

final class BasicServiceLocator: ServiceLocator {

    // Service registry
    private lazy var reg: Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]

    func addService<T>(instance: T) {
        let key = typeName(T)
        reg[key] = instance
        //print("Service added: \(key) / \(typeName(service))")
    }

    func getService<T>(type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return reg[typeName(T)] as? T
    }

}
```

And demonstration:

```
// Services declaration

protocol S1 {
    func f1() -> String
}

protocol S2 {
    func f2() -> String
}

// Services imlementation

class S1Impl: S1 {
    func f1() -> String {
        return "S1 OK"
    }
}

class S2Impl: S2 {
    func f2() -> String {
        return "S2 OK"
    }
}

// Service Locator initialization

let sl: ServiceLocator = {
    let sl = BasicServiceLocator()
    sl.addService(S1Impl() as S1)
    sl.addService(S2Impl() as S2)
    return sl
}()

// Test run

let s1 = sl.getService(S1)
let s2: S2? = sl.getService(S2)

print(s1?.f1() ?? "S1 NOT FOUND") // S1 OK
print(s2?.f2() ?? "S2 NOT FOUND") // S2 OK
```

Answer (score 1):

As one of the other posters pointed out, the Service Locator pattern is not actually DI.  Some would even go so far as to say [it's an anti-pattern](http://ilya.puchka.me/dependency-injection-in-swift/).

As a general answer to your question - I do believe first class DI is a better way to accomplish the above.  My suggestion would be to use [Typhoon](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon) but there are [several other DI libs](https://codix.io/cmp/Swift%20Dependency%20Injection%20Libs) available for Swift such as Cleanse which looks very promising.